# Negate only a particular string in regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

While parsing the following message in Python (using regex)

> message = 'OK - physical_ok:23/24 signal_up:23/24. Details: OK:span-1:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-2:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-3:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-4:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-5:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-6:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-7:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-8:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-9:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-10:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-11:alarmed:DOWN:Disconnected OK:span-12:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-13:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-14:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-15:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-16:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-17:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-18:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-19:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-20:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-21:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-22:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-23:ok:UP:Connected OK:span-24:ok:UP:Connected | physical_ok=23;24 signal_up=23;24\n'

The followng regex

```
re.findall('[A-Z]+:span-[0-9]+:[a-z]+:[A-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+', message)
```

returns

```
['OK:span-1:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-2:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-3:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-4:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-5:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-6:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-7:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-8:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-9:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-10:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-11:alarmed:DOWN:Disconnected',
 'OK:span-12:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-13:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-14:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-15:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-16:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-17:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-18:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-19:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-20:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-21:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-22:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-23:ok:UP:Connected',
 'OK:span-24:ok:UP:Connected']
```

I want to find all results other than the following string:

> "OK:span-[0-9]+:ok:UP:Connected"

For the above example the regex should only return `'OK:span-11:alarmed:DOWN:Disconnected'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a negative look-ahead to restrict the matches to the ones you want:

```
\b(?!OK:span-[0-9]+:ok:UP:Connected)[A-Z]+:span-[0-9]+:[a-z]+:[A-Z]+:[a-zA-Z]+\b
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV7tT3/2)

The lookahead makes sure we do not match substrings that we do not want (those starting with `OK:span-`, then some digits (`[0-9]`), and ending with `:ok:UP:Connected`).

Comment: Just FYI: If you use a raw string (`r'...'`) to initialize the regex, you would not need to double-escape special characters in the regex (if you add `\b`).

Comment: Hi, if i have a  string `CRITICAL:span-1:ok:UP:Connected`, I want my regex to match it too

Comment: other versions might be `CRITICAL:span-1:ok:DOWN:Connected` , `OK:span-1:ok:DOWN:Disconnected` . Sorry, if I wasn't clear in the first place.